# Fgets-How to prevent user from exceeding Maxsize?

Tags: c, fgets

I use fgets to get a name from the user and i put it in a char array.
If the user gives let's say beyond `maxsize` in `fgets`, then my program has a problem. I thought that if the user exceeds `maxsize`, `NULL` is returned. But that's not the case. How can i control this error?

Of course i can set `maxsize` at 200 and even more. But i think that's not a very good solution.

i have used `fgets` inside an `if` statement and if it's `==NULL`, i print an error, but as i already told that won't work if the user exceeds `maxsize`.

```
 fgets(name, 20, stdin);
```

Comment: Maybe allow up to `maxsize+1` input, and if the length of the name entered exceeds `maxsize` just don't accept the input. Also, try `gets()` and/or `gets_s()`. Not sure if it's exactly the same as `fgets(,,stdin)`, they are special functions for console-i/o.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as `fgets` is concerned, that's not an error. When you do `fgets(name, 20, stdin)`, it will simply read up to 19 characters from standard input (or less if one of the characters is `'\n'`). The remaining characters will remain in stdin and the next call to an input function will pick them up.

You can detect this case by checking for a successful call to `fgets` where the string does not contain `'\n'`:

```
if (!fgets(name, 20, stdin)) {
    // fgets failed; handle error
}
if (!strchr(name, '\n')) {
    // no newline in 'name'; a partial line was read
}
```

You then have the choice of allocating a bigger buffer, or throwing the rest of the line away, or complaining to the user.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try it. I know it's not an error but when the user exceeds maxsize i get a problem cause i have after fgets a scanf to read a number!

Comment: @Psz_13 warning, the fact there is no \n *can* signify you have more to read, but this is not mandatory, you can reach EOF without a \n.

Comment: @bruno True, but that's still a partial line as far as the C input model is concerned. It's just that when you reach EOF, you can never get a complete line (terminated by `\n`).

Comment: `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream)` is a practical alternative to _fgets_

Comment: @bruno Depends on what system OP is using. `getline` is not standard C.

Comment: @bruno POSIX is not standard C? POSIX extends C and adds functionality for systems that conform to POSIX. Linux does, windows doesn't. Unless you use WSL of course.

Comment: Or Cygwin. Forgot that.

Comment: " that's still a partial line as far as the C input model is concerned"  detail:  In C a last  _line_  with out a `'\n'` is complete or not depends on "Whether the
last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined."  §7.21.2 2

Comment: Corner case: `strchr(name, '\n')` works to find a read `'\n'` expect when a null character was read earlier.

Answer (score 0):

> Of course i can set maxsize at 200 and even more. But i think that's not a very good solution.

This approach is not so bad.

Creating some `my_gets()` that allows *huge* lines gives unlimited memory resource control over to user input - potential hacker exploit.  An huge line is more likely errant input or a nefarious code hack.

I'd go with [@Constantine Georgiou](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56405267/fgets-how-to-prevent-user-from-exceeding-maxsize#comment99408355_56405267) and use a large, but sane upper limit.  Then detect such large lines as errant/hostile.

Note that text file lines have an *environmental limit*.  So proving huge buffers can be moot.

> An implementation shall support text files with lines containing at least 254 characters, including the terminating new-line character. The value of the macro BUFSIZ shall be at least 256. C11 §7.21.2 7

```
#define MY_BUFSIZE ((BUFSIZE < 4096) ? BUFSIZE : 4096)

char name[MY_BUFSIZE + 2];
if (fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin)) {
  if (strlen(name) >= MY_BUFSIZE) Too_long_error();
```

Note: Input unusually reads in a *null character* rendering     `fgets()` problematic.